# Generate list of dates based on the day and occurrence of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to generate based on the day of the week and number of the occurrence in the month of a date, a list of dates for each month between two dates. Assuming I have a `@StartDate = 2016/04/01` and `@EndDate = 2016/09/01`, i check that `@StartDate` is on a first Friday of April, then to `@EndDate` will create dates for all first Friday of each month:

```
2016/05/06
2016/06/03
2016/07/01
2016/08/05
```

In case `@StartDate = 2016/04/12` and `@EndDate = 2016/09/01`, I note that the `@StartDate` is the second Tuesday of April, then went to get every second Tuesday Tuesday of each month :

```
2016/05/10
2016/06/14
2016/07/12
2016/08/09
```

In case`@StartDate = 2016/04/28` and `@EndDate = 2016/09/01`, I note that the `@StartDate` is on the last Thursday of the month of April:

```
2016/05/26
2016/06/30
2016/07/28
2016/08/25
```

In the last case, i need to verify the number of weeks of each month, because exists months only with 4 weeks or with 5 weeks and i want the last occurrence.

What I have done? I found a code that gives me every Monday in the third week of the month, and i adopted a little to get a `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`:

```
;with  
 filler as (select row_number() over (order by a) a from (select top 100 1 as a from syscolumns) a cross join (select top 100 1 as b from syscolumns) b),
 dates as (select dateadd(month, a-1, @StartDate ) date from filler where a <= 1000 and dateadd(month, a-1, @StartDate) < @EndDate),
 FirstMonday as (
 select dateadd(day, case   datepart(weekday,Date) /*this is the case where verify the week day*/
                            when 1 then 1 
                            when 2 then 0
                            when 3 then 6
                            when 4 then 5 
                            when 5 then 4 
                            when 6 then 3
                            when 7 then 2
                        end, Date) as Date 
        ,case when datepart(weekday, @StartDate) = 1 then 3 else 2 end as Weeks /*here i verify the number of weeks to sum in the next date*/
 from   dates
 )
 select dateadd(week, Weeks, Date) as ThirdMonday
 from FirstMonday
```

Comment: Your rules are ambiguous.  How do you distinguish between the fourth Monday in a month and the last Monday?

Comment: @GordonLinoff you speak about the code? I need to adapt it to do this

Comment: Have you considered using a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)?  From a full list of all dates, with weekdays and week numbers included, you would always to be able to filter for just the dates you need.

Comment: @destination-data calendar table is a temporary table? And how it can help me?

Comment: It is in the example, but it could be a full table on your instance.  Calendar tables are handy for all kinds of things.  In your case filtering the calendar table (rough example: `SELECT * FROM Calendar WHERE WeekDay = 'Monday' AND WeekNumber = 4`) is much easier than dynamically building the dates.

Comment: Does this have to be in SQL only or can it be T-SQL?

Comment: @RudyTheHunter in SQL

Comment: @destination-data yes, i understand. But i will have the same problem to get the last weekDay in month, because i have months with four weeks and others with five weeks

Comment: Your table could include a field that identifies the final week of each month.  This is where these tables really come into their own.  They allow you to tag and identify what's important to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it is:

```
set @NumSemana = datepart(day, datediff(day, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,@StartDate), 0), @StartDate)/7 * 7)/7 + 1;
WITH    AllDays
  AS ( SELECT  @StartDate  AS [Date], DATEPART(month, @StartDate) as validMonth
       UNION ALL
       SELECT   DATEADD(week, 1, [Date]), 
                iif(DATEPART(month,DATEADD(week, 1, [Date])) < validMonth + @PeriodicityRepeat, validMonth, validMonth + @PeriodicityRepeat)
       FROM     AllDays
       WHERE    
            DATEPART(month,[Date]) <= DATEPART(month,@EndDate)
        and DATEPART(year,[Date]) <= DATEPART(year,@EndDate)
            ),
rankedDays 
  AS(     
    SELECT [Date], validMonth, 
           row_number() over ( partition by DATEPART( month, [Date]) order by [Date]) ascOrder,
           row_number() over ( partition by DATEPART( month, [Date]) order by [Date] desc) descOrder
    FROM   AllDays 
    WHERE DATEPART(month, [Date]) = validMonth
)
select [Date]
from rankedDays
where ((ascOrder = @NumSemana and @NumSemana <=4 )  
        or (descOrder = 1 and @NumSemana = 5) 
        or [Date] = @StartDate )
   and [Date] < @EndDate 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Query**:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2016-04-28',
        @EndDate DATE = '2016-09-01'

;WITH dates AS (
SELECT DATEADD(week, -5, @StartDate) as date_
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(week,1,date_)
FROM dates
WHERE DATEADD(week,1,date_) < @enddate
), final AS (
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(year,date_), DATEPART(month,date_) ORDER BY date_ ASC) as RN,
        date_
FROM dates
), weeks AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1,1),
(2,2),
(3,3),
(4,4),
(4,5),
(5,4),
(5,5)
) as t(w1,w2)
WHERE w1 = (SELECT RN FROM final WHERE date_ = @StartDate)
)


SELECT MAX(date_) as date_
FROM final f
INNER JOIN weeks w ON f.RN = w.w2
WHERE date_ between @StartDate and @EndDate AND date_ != @StartDate
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,date_), DATEPART(MONTH,date_)
ORDER BY MAX(date_) ASC
```

**Outputs**:

For `@StartDate = 2016/04/01` and `@EndDate = 2016/09/01`

```
date_
----------
2016-05-06
2016-06-03
2016-07-01
2016-08-05

(4 row(s) affected)
```

For `@StartDate = 2016/04/12` and `@EndDate = 2016/09/01`

```
date_
----------
2016-05-10
2016-06-14
2016-07-12
2016-08-09

(4 row(s) affected)
```

For `@StartDate = 2016/04/28` and `@EndDate = 2016/09/01`

```
date_
----------
2016-05-26
2016-06-30
2016-07-28
2016-08-25

(4 row(s) affected)
```